# set highlight color of lua basic functions in scintilla control

Tags: lua, scintilla, scilexer.dll

I am using scintilla edit control in an MFC dialog based app.

I load scilexer.dll, and set the lexer to lua, but the only thing that is getting highlighted is the comments. I can also set keywords and they get highlighted:

```
mySciCtrl.SendMessage(SCI_SETKEYWORDS, 0, "for while end function")
```

However, I can not figure out how to enable highlighting of say lua basic functions like `print`, `setmetatable`, etc.

I thought that would be automatic just like the comments highlighting. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Found it, it was pretty trivial of course just needed to look at the scintilla functions. So, if anyone else runs into this:

in your scintilla window class initilize color by using `SendMessage(SCI_STYLESETFORE, SCE_LUA_WORD2, RGB(100,149,237));` for a second list of keywords.

Then in your dialog do `m_ScinCtrl.SendMessage( SCI_SETKEYWORDS, 1, ( long )_T( "the words you want highlighted with the above specified color"));`

`SCE_LUA_WORD2` corresponds to integer value 1 in the second statement so if you want a third set of keywords highlighted differently just use `SCE_LUA_WORD3` and integer value 2 in the second statement!